# Efficient computation of Chirp Z Transform

Tags: fft, algorithms, z-transform, reference-request

Chirp Z Transform ([1](http://www.embedded.com/design/configurable-systems/4006427/A-DSP-algorithm-for-frequency-analysis), [2](http://www.katjaas.nl/chirpZ/chirpZ.html), [3](http://www.eurasip.org/Proceedings/Eusipco/Eusipco2014/HTML/papers/1569925105.pdf)) is more powerful than zooming techniques (I use it to actually trace non-stationary chirp signals) and very usable in signal processing, but it's flexibility comes at price - the general CZT needs $3 \times FFT$, using Bluestein convolution algorithm.
Although generaly one if them can be precomputed - I have to perform full three rounds.

Is it possible to perform general Chirp Z Transform faster than using Bluestein algorithm (namely faster than $3 \times FFT$)?